# Serial No Based On Column Info Required In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have few columns in my table (SQL Server 2000 database). I have information like

```
OrderID      Design        Qty
------------------------------    
28500   R6192WHM+DWN    1
28500   P3150WHM+DWN    1
28504   E3085/2DWN  1
28503   R5595HCT(P) 1
28503   R4768DWN    1
28505   E3415D(P)   1
28505   E3413DWN    1
28505   E3365AQ(P)  1
```

I require information like this (i.e sno based on orderid )

```
OrderID   Design        Qty    SNO
-------------------------------------    
28500   R6192WHM+DWN    1       1
28500   P3150WHM+DWN    1       2
28504   E3085/2DWN  1       1
28503   R5595HCT(P) 1       1
28503   R4768DWN    1       2 
28505   E3415D(P)   1       1
28505   E3413DWN    1       2
28505   E3365AQ(P)  1       3
```

Comment: Do you mean SQL *Server*? SQL by itself is a generic language, and although there are hints in your post, you don't actually ever state that it *is* SQL Server. Also, it's not clear how `SNO` is based on `OrderID` and `Design` in your sample - it appears to only depend on `OrderID`. Finally, is this something being done for display purposes or to be stored - and does it need to be stable or avoid gaps if deletions occur?

Comment: for transfer purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select t1.*, SNO = count(*)
  from Table1 t1
  join Table1 t2
    on t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
   and t1.Design >= t2.Design
 group by t1.OrderID, t1.Design, t1.Qty
 order by t1.OrderID, t1.Design
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, which works in MS Sql sever 2005 and above:

```
select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by OrderID order by OrderID) 
from YourTable
```

Sample

```
select 
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by OrderID order by OrderID) 
from(
    select 28500 OrderID,   'R6192WHM+DWN' Design,  1 Qty union
    select 28500 OrderID,   'P3150WHM+DWN' Design,  1 Qty union
    select 28504 OrderID,   'E3085/2DWN' Design,    1 Qty union
    select 28503 OrderID,   'R5595HCT(P)' Design,   1 Qty union
    select 28503 OrderID,   'R4768DWN' Design,      1 Qty union
    select 28505 OrderID,   'E3415D(P)' Design,     1 Qty union
    select 28505 OrderID,   'E3413DWN' Design,      1 Qty union
    select 28505 OrderID,   'E3365AQ(P)' Design,    1 Qty
)x
```

Please try the below query, which works in sql server 2000
`select 
    *, 
    (select count(*) from YourTable t2 where t2.OrderId=t1.OrderID and t2.Design<t1.Design)+1 as SNo 
From YourTable t1 
order by OrderID, Design`

Comment: row_number() has bee introduced since sql server 2005.